# C# ASP .NET Entity Framework select from multiple nested tables

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, entity-framework, ado.net

Hello I'm trying to get data from nested tables with select. I've four tables Pins, Tags, Media and MediaTags, Pins can have multiple media and each Media can have multiple Tags, Now I'm trying to query Pins where Tags Title contains search string.

Here is what i have
[image]

Here is code I'm trying to do, How can i proceed further?

```
public async Task<List<Pins>> Search(string query, string pageNum, string Category) 
        {
            try
            {
                int _pageNum = int.Parse(pageNum);
                int _skip = _pageNum * MaxNumOfPinsPerCall;
                using (var context = new Entities()) 
                {
                    var srchrslt = context.Pins
                            .Where(p =>
                            p.About.Contains(query)
                            || p.Title.Contains(query)
                            || p.Alt.Contains(query)
                            || p.Media.Tags.Title.Contains(query))
                            .Skip(_skip)
                            .Take(MaxNumOfPinsPerCall)
                            .Include("Media")
                            .ToList();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: How can i include those pins which media's tags having specific titles matching with search query, how can i do that? @ErikEJ

Answer (score 0):

The Tags table is two levels deep, you need to use `ThenInclude`

```
context.Pins
    .Include(p => p.Media)
    .ThenInclude(m => m.Tags)
```

Comment: Hello, I'm using .NET Web Api, *ThenInclude* only works in .NET Core. Can you please explain how can i compare query with Tag's Title so i'll include only those pins which Pin's Media has specific titles matching to search query.